# How Do I Authenticate In Sequelize?

Tags: node.js, authentication, express, sequelize.js

I have a route that I must authenticate by getting sequelize to search for any instance of an existing username and password in the request body in order to know if I can go ahead and authenticate the user. I'm not sure how to do this (search and check instances in Sequelize) because documentation is pretty new for Sequelize. I attempted User.findOne by reading here http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest/api/model/ for example

```
db.User.findOne({
    where: { password: req.password, username: req.username }

}).then(function(address) {
    if(address.User !== null) {
        console.log('User name: '+address.User.name);
    } else {
        console.log('User name: NO USER');
    }
```

But not sure of the exact syntax/approach. I have something like this:

```
app.post('/authenticate', function (req, res) {
  //TODO validate req.body.username and req.body.password
  //if is invalid, return 401


  if (!(req.body.username === 'john.doe' && req.body.password === 'foobar')) {
    res.status(401).send('Wrong user or password');
    return;
  }

  var profile = {
    first_name: 'John',
    last_name: 'Doe',
    email: 'john@doe.com',
    id: 123
  };

  // We are sending the profile inside the token
  var token = jwt.sign(profile, secret, { expiresIn: 18000 });

  res.json({ token: token });
});

app.get('/api/restricted', function (req, res) {
  console.log('user ' + req.user.email + ' is calling /api/restricted');
  res.json({
    name: 'foo'
  });
});
```